# Call fragment from activity on back pressed?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using navigation drawer and fragment to show the component on selecting navigation option.And if user select navigation drawer option a fragment will open. So my problem is when I call a activity from fragment and when I press back button it call previous fragment but the content of that fragment remain same. What I want is when I press back button from activity it should open my fragment or recall fragment and values should be blank like first time we call the fragment.

Thanks.

Comment: Remove and add the fragment again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I didn't understand.I want to call the previous fragment from the activity on back button press.

Comment: Override the `onBackPressed` method in your Activity.

Comment: I want to recall the fragment on back button press from activity.It just display the previous loaded data.e.g. I have set string then it remain same when come back using back button from activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getTitle().equals("Title")) {                
            YourFragment fragment =new YourFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```